# Catch exception for testing

Tags: error-handling, f#

I am currently undergoing a course in F#. I am working on a black-box test for a function that I have rewritten in relation to an assignment. During this test I am supposed to test the function by inputting a wrong format (giving a string to a function that expects an int) I would like to be able to catch the exception and allow the test to keep running instead of exiting. How can I accomplish this in f#?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
#r "msort.dll"

let tests = [
    ("Sorted lists", [
        ([1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10], [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]);
        ([5000;6000;7000;8000;9000;10000;11000;12000;13000;14000], [5000;6000;7000;8000;9000;10000;11000;12000;13000;14000]);
        ([10;9;8;7;6;5;4;3;2;1], [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10]);
        ([14000;13000;12000;11000;10000;9000;8000;7000;6000;5000], [5000;6000;7000;8000;9000;10000;11000;12000;13000;14000]);
    ])
    ("Wrong input formats", [
        ([], []);
        (["hello"], []);
    ])
]

printfn "Black-box testing of Merge Sort"
for i = 0 to tests.Length-1 do
    let (testName, testSet) = tests.[i]
    printfn "%d. %s" (i+1) testName
    for j = 0 to testSet.Length - 1 do
        try
            let (input, expected) = testSet.[j]
            let result = (msort.sort input)
            printfn "test %d - %b" (j+1) (result = expected)
        with
            | _ as ex -> printfn "error occured"
```

I was thinking that I could catch any exception with the wildcard and continue the test after printing the string "error occured" but the program simply closes with the exception:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int'    
but here has type
    'string'
```

The function I am testing is a version of merge-sort rewritten to use pattern matching. Here is the code for the function, that is compiled into "msort.dll"

```
module msort

let rec merge (xs:int list) (ys:int list): int list =
  match xs with
    | []  -> ys                   // if xs is empty return ys
    | xs when ys = [] -> xs       // if ys is empty return xs
    | _   ->                      // if non of the above is true
      let x = List.head xs
      let y = List.head ys
      let xs = List.tail xs
      let ys = List.tail ys
      match x with
        | x when x <= y -> x :: merge xs (y::ys) // if x < y merge x
        | x when x > y -> y :: merge (x::xs) ys // else merge y
        | _ -> []                               // otherwise something is wrong, return empty array

let rec sort (xs:int list): int list =
  let sz = List.length xs
  if sz < 2 then xs           // if the length of sz is under 2 we cannot split and so we return xs
  else let n = sz / 2
       let ys = xs.[0..n-1]   // ys = the first half of the input array
       let zs = xs.[n..sz-1]  // zs = the second half of the input array
       in merge (sort ys) (sort zs) // call merge with each half
```

Comment: That's not an exception, it's a compiler error.

Comment: Here's a hint: what is the type of `tests`?

Comment: You are right it sure is, but let me rephrase. Is there a way to compile with these errors? The error is supposed to happen, but I want to be able to execute the program with these errors. The type of tests is an array with tuples and sub arrays.

Comment: you are trying to be too clever with your original list. It's a compile error, so obviously you cannot compile with it. and a compile error on the line with `["hello"]`. This means that irrespective of what you are doing in the rest of the program, this list is not valid F# code. You can certainly catch invalid input, test for it, etc. You could even test for throwing the correct exception on invalid input with a testing library like xUnit or Expecto. But first, break up your lists into good lists and bad lists. Probably you would want something like FsCheck for property based testing.

Comment: @s952163 Thank you for your elaborate answer. So I need to be able to distinguish in advance between valid and invalid input and handle it correctly based on this. Instead of just putting valid input together with invalid input and trying to parse everything in one go. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: The first thing you need to internalize is that _F# is a statically typed language_ (look it up if you don't know what it means). Once you understand this, try to answer this question: _what is the type of your variable `tests`_?

Comment: yes, tbh, what you are trying to imitate, actually makes sense, but you need to represent it better in your code for testing. This type of situation can occur when your input comes from the outside, hence it's inpure (so in Haskell you have the IO Monad), obviously if you are reading this from a file (or somebody typing into  a textbox) you have no control what will come through. You can than handle it on the input side and validate, or pass it through and catch the exception. You can make your function generic so it could accept all kinds of stuff but throw an exception when it's not `int`.

Comment: Really informative comments. I understand why my question is based on a flawed use of the tests and the principle of static types in f# and have accepted Tomas Petricek's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no reason for writing tests that would try to call your `sort` function with an input of invalid type - the F# compiler will check such cases statically and will block those, so nobody can call the function with a list of strings if it expects a list of integers.

Something like what you are trying to do would only make sense if you had a function that is not statically type safe. For example, if you had `unsafeSort` that converts all inputs into integers before sorting them. You can define a function like that using `System.Convert` and casting via `:?>`.

This is very ugly and unsafe and you should never actually do this, because it defeats the purpose of using F# with static types, but you can technically do it:

```
let unsafeSort list = 
  msort.sort [ for v in list -> System.Convert.ChangeType(v, typeof<int>) :?> int ]
  |> List.map box
```

Then you could represent data for your tests as objects, which will let you mix strings and integers:

```
let tests = [
    ("Sorted lists", [
        ([box 1;box 3;box 2], [box 1;box 2;box 3]);
    ])
    ("Wrong input formats", [
        (["hello"], []);
    ])
]
```

And running the tests using the following will report one pass and one error:

```
for testName, testSet in tests do
  for input, expected in testSet do
    try
        let result = unsafeSort input
        printfn "- %b" (result = expected)
    with
        | _ as ex -> printfn "error occured"
```

As mentioned before, this is just to answer your question from the technical side - doing this is a very bad idea.